# How to use OCLint for the Cocoa Framework?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-analysis, xcodebuild, oclint

Run the following command in the folder with the project:

```
$ xcodebuild -target MyCocoaFramework -configuration Debug -scheme MyCocoaFramework clean build | tee xcodebuild.log
$ oclint-xcodebuild
$ oclint-json-compilation-database
$
```

Nothing is displayed.
This approach works fine for Cocoa Application.

```
$ xcodebuild -target MyCocoaApplication -configuration Debug -scheme MyCocoaApplication clean build | tee xcodebuild.log
$ oclint-xcodebuild
$ oclint-json-compilation-database
/a/b/c/d.m:181:5: redundant local variable P3 
/a/b/c/d/e.m:193:5: redundant local variable P3 
/a/b/c/d.m:104:1: long line P3 Line with 112 characters exceeds limit of 100
```

What should be changed to work for the Cocoa Framework?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your project structure? What is being included in the targets 'MyCocoaApplication' and 'MyCocoaFramework'?

Answer (score 0):

OCLint can't support the arm64 architecture: https://github.com/oclint/oclint/issues/190

If your code targets iOS 7, then OCLint may fail silently.

Comment: And...are there definitely issues in MyCocoaFramework that should be flagged by OCLint?